# How to check if any element in array is also an array

Tags: ruby

I want to check if `array` has any elements that are instances of `Array`. I could make a recursive function and that iterates and finds all elements that are `Array`. Is there a shorter way to do this?

**Get all elements that are of x type and manipulate them (i.e. modify or delete them)**

Comment: `arr.flatten.size > arr.size` works, but @sawa's answer is more efficient and reads better.

Comment: @CarySwoveland `array.flatten == array` may work.

Comment: i need to delete items recursively

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "delete items recursively", or more generally, your reference to recursion. This couldn't concern deeply nested arrays, for example, because if you delete an array `a` from `arr` everything within `a` is gone, of course. Moreover, it would make no sense to start at the "bottom" and work up, because when you get to the "top" and deleted the element `a` of `arr`, all your previous work would have been just a waste of time--those deletions would have occurred anyway had you just deleted `a` in the first place.

Comment: i meant delete element x even in nested arrays

Comment: Can you edit your question to describe the problem you're actually trying to solve? In your comments you mention deleting items recursively but in your question you only mention checking if an array has any elements that are arrays. Those are two very different tasks.

Answer (score 4):

It can be done this way:

```
array.any?{|e| e.is_a?(Array)}
```

Comment: This will only check if the top level `array` has any elements that are arrays, but will not check the sub arrays (and sub-sub arrays and so on) as the OP requested.

Comment: @neuronaut I cannot understand your comment under the OP's description. "check the sub arrays (and sub-sub arrays and so on)" is not what OP requested.

Comment: It looks like the OP is asking to find instances of arrays and then search those arrays for instances of arrays, and so on, recursively. At least, I think that's what's meant by "I could make a recursive function and that iterates and finds all elements"

Comment: @neuronaut That is the OP's solution, which does not do what the OP asked for. Furthermore, how can an array have a subarray without having an array as its direct element? You mean that it may be embedded in some (non-array) construct that is an element of the array?

Comment: You can't, of course. But if you have this: `[1, 2, [:a, :b, ['x', 'y'], :c], 3]` you're code won't find the ['x', 'y'] array (which I think is what the OP is asking for?). Or, as you also mention, you could have this: `[1, 2, {a: [3, 4]}]` which would mean `[3, 4]` would not be found.

Comment: The OP is asking "**if** array has ....", which is answered either by yes (`true`) or no (`false`).

Comment: good point, I was focusing more on the bit about recursiveness.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one possible solution,
You can use [Ruby blocks](http://www.reactive.io/tips/2008/12/21/understanding-ruby-blocks-procs-and-lambdas/) to act on sub-arrays & nested sub-arrays recursively.

```
arr = [1, [2,3], [4,[5,6]]]

def act_on_array(arr, block) 
    arr.each do |i|  
        if i.is_a?(Array) then
            block.yield(i)
            act_on_array(i, block)
        end
    end 
end

act_on_array(arr, lambda {|x| puts "I should act on #{x} as it is an array" })
```

**Output of program**

```
I should act on [2, 3] as it is an array
I should act on [4, [5, 6]] as it is an array
I should act on [5, 6] as it is an array
```